# Artifactory trigger for gitlab

Tags: build, triggers, gitlab, artifactory

Which ways are there to get a gitlab pipeline triggered when a new artifact becomes available in a certain artifactory location? E.g. like Jenkins Artifactory Trigger: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in or TeamCity: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/TeamCity+Artifactory+Plug-in#TeamCityArtifactoryPlug-in-TriggeringBuildsinReactiontoChangesinArtifactory.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Artifactory GitLab CI plugin, like you listed for Jenkins and TeamCity, but you can use JFrog CLI to integrate GitLab CI and Artifactory.
Check out this blog:
https://jfrog.com/blog/gitlab-and-artifactory-on-your-mark-get-set-build/